# How do I get the number of Steam friends online programmatically?

Tags: steam

How can I get the current number of Steam friends online in order to insert it into a script or program? I'm looking to use this value to do something like changing an LED colour or for providing data for a desktop widget etc.

Is this possible? How do I get access to that number?

P.S. I got my idea from here: [Xbox Live Traffic Light Notifies You When Friends are Gaming](https://lifehacker.com/xbox-live-traffic-light-notifies-you-when-friends-are-g-5949565?IR=T)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steam does not support it, but there is a workaround to get it done programmatically. However, private profiles will *not* work, so you will not be able to see a friend's status, even if they allowed you to see it. The API is *public* and it will only be able to see  and parse public profiles.

In short you need to query Steam's [web API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API) in a loop:

1. `GetFriendList` - get all friends of that account
2. For each friend use `GetPlayerSummaries` and the `personastate` in the returned result will include their online status.
3. Save results, repeat, compare.